# How I can fill the video component in container?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to style video so that It will fill the remaining space, but nothing is working so far, anyone has any idea what I can do here:

```
export const VIDEO_STYLES = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    alignSelf: "stretch",
    objectFit: 'cover',
}


React.cloneElement(videoComponent, { style: VIDEO_STYLES })
```

[image]